# Angular How to wrap a class="row" around the loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<li *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
   <a href="{{ '/' + (category[0] | lowercase) + '-invitations/invite/all-cards' }}">{{ category[0] }}</a>
</li>
```

Required output:

```
<div class="row">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</div>
```

Any help?
Please someone have look
Please someone have look
Please someone have look

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Side note: `li` is not a valid child element for `div`. More: [`li`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), [`div`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element).

Comment: how does `categories` look like?

Comment: categories are in array

Comment: So you want to show 4 items next to each other on the screen? Also are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your categories and iterate about the group.

```
//In your component.ts create a "getter"

get groupCategories(){
   let groupCategories:any[]=[];
   let j=-1;
   for (let i=0;i<this.categories.length;i++)
   {
       if ((i%4)==0)
       {
         groupCategories.push([]);
         j++;
       }
       groupCategories[j].push(this.categories[i]);
   }
   console.log(groupCategories);
   return groupCategories;
}
```

Comment: Can write it as `if (i % 4 === 0) {` to.

Comment: This will not work btw first of all `groupCategories[j]` be undefined when push.

Comment: :glups: the code was wrong. I have just corrected yet